# Setter not working in model

Tags: go, setter

I am making this code trying to understand the MVC architecture while learning Go, and I am stuck trying to change values in the model from the controller.

The code right now creates a model that only holds a string, the view shows that string on the terminal, but the controller can not change it (it gets the user input without any problem).

Right now the text I get in the terminal is like this:

```
Hello World!
asdf //my input
Hello World!
```

And the output I would like to get would be like this:

```
Hello World!
asdf //my input
asdf
```

Here are my files:

model.go

```
package models

type IndexModel struct {
    Text string
}

func (m *IndexModel) InitModel() string {
    return m.Text
}

func (m *IndexModel) SetText(newText string) {
    m.Text = newText
}
```

view.go

```
package views

import "github.com/jufracaqui/mvc_template/app/models"

type IndexView struct {
    Model    models.IndexModel
}

func (v IndexView) Output() string {
    return v.Model.Text
}
```

controller.go

```
package controllers

import "github.com/jufracaqui/mvc_template/app/models"

type IndexController struct {
    Model models.IndexModel
}

func (c IndexController) ChangeText(userInput string) {
    c.Model.SetText(userInput)
}
```

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"

    "fmt"

    "github.com/jufracaqui/mvc_template/app/controllers"
    "github.com/jufracaqui/mvc_template/app/models"
    "github.com/jufracaqui/mvc_template/app/views"
)

func main() {
    handleIndex()
}

func handleIndex() {
    model := models.IndexModel{
        "Hello World!",
    }

    controller := controllers.IndexController{
        model,
    }

    viewIndex := views.IndexView{
        model,
    }

    fmt.Println(viewIndex.Model.Text)

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    controller.ChangeText(text)
    fmt.Println(viewIndex.Model.Text)
}
```

**Edit:**
How my code ended up after @JimB answer:

model.go:

```
package models

type IndexModel struct {
    Text string
}

func (m *IndexModel) InitModel() string {
    return m.Text
}
```

view.go:

```
package views

import "github.com/jufracaqui/mvc_template/app/models"

type IndexView struct {
    Model    *models.IndexModel
}

func (v IndexView) Output() string {
    return v.Model.Text
}
```

controller.go:

```
package controllers

import "github.com/jufracaqui/mvc_template/app/models"

type IndexController struct {
    Model *models.IndexModel
}

func (c IndexController) ChangeText(userInput string) {
    c.Model.Text = userImput
}
```

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"

    "fmt"

    "github.com/jufracaqui/mvc_template/app/controllers"
    "github.com/jufracaqui/mvc_template/app/models"
    "github.com/jufracaqui/mvc_template/app/views"
)

func main() {
    handleIndex()
}

func handleIndex() {
    model := models.IndexModel{
        "Hello World!",
    }

    m := &model

    controller := controllers.IndexController{
        m,
    }

    viewIndex := views.IndexView{
        m,
    }

    fmt.Println(viewIndex.Model.Text)

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    controller.ChangeText(text)
    fmt.Println(viewIndex.Model.Text)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IndexController.ChangeText` needs a pointer receiver, or `IndexController.Model` needs to be a pointer. You're calling `SetText` on a copy of the `SetText` value.

If you expect things to be mutable, it's much easier to consistently use pointers to structs throughout, and make explicit struct values the exception when you really need them.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't mark this as a duplicate of the ever-so-many struct setter questions. This one indeed has some subtle differences.